# HTML Symbol for following symbol

Tags: html, special-characters

Is there an HTML code for the following image below:

[image: HTML Code for Arrows]

Comment: Look no further: https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref

Comment: @lumio I tried that site. Was not able to find the correct pointing guillemet

Comment: I don't think you find the exact image. What font is that anyway?

Comment: @lumio: times new roman

Comment: You still could use it's UTF8 charcode value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code `&#10147;` is probably as close as you'll get (it's for a right-pointing arrow, I don't know the code for the corresponding left=pointing one, but one may exist) In any case, you could always `transform` it using `rotateY` like so:

(EDIT: `&#x27A4;` also close, but right-pointing also)

```css
.arrows {
  -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  text-align:right;
}
```

```html
<p class="arrows">&#10147;&#10147;&#10147;</p>

<p class="arrows">&#x27A4;&#x27A4;&#x27A4;</p>
```

Hope this helps